# How to clear the SSL state in modern Chrome and Fire Fox browser

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, certificate

I need to clear the SSL state when the user clicks logout, I see some older method like

```
document.execCommand("ClearAuthenticationCache", false);
```

and

```
window.crypto.logout();
```

**But when I use this in the modern browser it is not working.**

So how to achieve this functionality in modern browser

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean with SSL state, i.e. what is your intended effect of "clearing the SSL state"?

Comment: when I login the web app it initially asks for a certificate selection, and after selection it takes the user to the dashboard page. But when the user logs out and tries to log in again, I need to have the certificate selection again. But currently its not working like that and directly goes to dashboard page. But when I close the browser and try to login again it is asking for certificate selection.
Similarly I need to show the certificate selection every time if the user logs out the site. To achieve this functionality I am trying to clear the SSL state.

Comment: @Steffen Ullrich Also please refer this link
https://textslashplain.com/2020/10/19/client-certificates-and-logout/