# How to clear the SSL state in modern chrome and fire fox browser?

Tags: authentication, security, ssl, multi-factor-authentication

I need to clear the SSL state when the user clicks logout, I see  some older method like

document.execCommand("ClearAuthenticationCache", false);

AND

window.crypto.logout();

But when I use this in the modern browser it is not working.

so how to achieve this functionally in modern browser.

Comment: This questions looks identical to https://stackoverflow.com/q/74781591/238704. Please don't post the same questions from multiple accounts.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it appears to be a copy of https://stackoverflow.com/q/74781591.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the sessionStorage or localStorage APIs to store a flag that indicates whether the user is logged in or not. Then, when the user clicks logout, you can clear the SSL state and set the flag to false to indicate that the user is no longer logged in.

```
# Set the loggedIn flag to true when the user logs in
sessionStorage.setItem('loggedIn', true);

# Clear the SSL state and set the loggedIn flag to false when the user logs out
function logout() {
clearSSLState(); # implement this function to clear the SSL state
sessionStorage.setItem('loggedIn', false);
}
```

But sessionStorage API stores data in the user's browser for the current session only. If the user closes the browser or the session ends, the data will be cleared.

Comment: *"when the user clicks logout, you can clear the SSL state"* - how to clear the SSL state is what was asked, but is not answered here.